# Creating a managed structure for data

Tags: c#, data-structures, struct, marshalling

Last night I was working on cleaning up some code I found that was a port of an old game I used to play. One of the tricks I used to clean up data was to get rid of the home-brew `DataOffsetAttribute` that was made for a struct and just make it a plain jane struct and then I can (later) convert it to something a little more useful. Kind of like a person would do with a DataLayer. This worked really good for fixed sized data from a file. Using this method I was about to convert between the two "data types".

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T dataStructure) where T : struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(dataStructure);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(dataStructure, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}

public static T MarshalAs<T>(this byte[] rawDataStructure) where T : struct
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(type);
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.Copy(rawDataStructure, 0, ptr, size);
    T structure = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, type);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return structure;
}
```

So then I started to wonder if this would work on another project I worked on a long time ago where the data was variable. Here is what I was hoping my data structure would look like

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct RfidReaderResponse
{
    public byte PreambleA;
    public byte PreambleB;
    public byte Length;
    public byte LengthLRC;
    public ushort ReaderId;
    public byte CommandId;
    public byte ErrorCode;
    public byte[] Data;
    public byte LRC;
}
```

I would probably combine the preamble bytes into a ushort and check if it is a specific value... but that is a different discussion. I have 3 known good responses that I used for testing back in the day. I put those into linqpad as well as my hopeful datastructure. So here is what I am currently using for testing

```
void Main()
{
    var readerResponses = new string[] 
    {
        //data is null because of error EC
        "AA-BB-05-05-02-39-0C-EC-21", 
        //data is 44-00
        "AA-BB-07-07-02-39-0C-00-44-00-8B", 
         //data is 44-00-20-04-13-5E-1A-A4-33-80
        "AA-BB-0F-0F-02-39-10-00-44-00-20-04-13-5E-1A-A4-33-80-FB",
    };
    readerResponses
        .Select(x=> x.ToByteArray().MarshalAs<RfidReaderResponse>())
        .Dump();
}
```

now if I comment out the last two fields of the struct I get back what I expect for the first part of the response, but I am just lost on how to get back the data portion. I would prefer to have it as I have it with some magical attribute that the Marshaler understands but so far I can't figure it out. I have tried

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct RfidReaderResponse
{
    public byte PreambleA;
    public byte PreambleB;
    public byte Length;
    public byte LengthLRC;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] 
    public IntPtr Data;
}
```

and

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct RfidReaderResponse
{
    public byte PreambleA;
    public byte PreambleB;
    public byte Length;
    public byte LengthLRC;
    public ushort ReaderId;
    public byte CommandId;
    public byte ErrorCode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_I1)]
    public byte[] Data;
    public byte LRC;
}
```

after a few hours of research. Both of which didn't work stating that my method couldn't make a size for my structure. So I dunno. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

forgot the method for converting hex strings to byte arrays

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this string hexString)
{
    hexString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(hexString, "[^0-9A-F.]", "").ToUpper();
    if (hexString.Length % 2 == 1)
        throw new Exception("The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits");

    byte[] arr = new byte[hexString.Length >> 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length >> 1; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = (byte)((GetHexVal(hexString[i << 1]) << 4) + (GetHexVal(hexString[(i << 1) + 1])));
    }

    return arr;
}

private static int GetHexVal(char hex)
{
    int val = (int)hex;
    return val - (val < 58 ? 48 : 55);
}
```

Comment: Do you want the actual bytes in the `Data` array to be part of the structure, or do you want to store a reference to the array in the structure?

Comment: I'd prefer the actual bytes, but i'd take either

Comment: The actual bytes in the array is possible in unsafe code (see [Fixed Size Buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx), but only if it's fixed size. In .NET, a a struct must be a fixed size. It seems like there should be a `MarshalAs` attribute that would turn a block of bytes into an array and supply a reference, but I don't see a way to do that without creating a custom marshaler.

Comment: @JimMischel ok. So can we use a reference than? I don't mind doing some magic to make the data work? when I get the whole blob the response[2] gives me the length from the ReaderId to the end. Currently in code  I use LINQ to read in the data bit something like `response.Skip(4).Take(response[2]).ToArray()`